# Implementing IMAP Idle using Rebex in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, imap, rebex

I have created a .net  mail client application using Rebex library and want to implement something like 'push mail' system and I came to know IMAP allow this which is called as IMAP IDLE, any one having any idea how can I implement this in my application, looking for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebex IMAP does support IDLE - use `Imap` object's `CheckForUpdates(int duration)` method - this instructs the IMAP session to the IDLE state for the specified amount of miliseconds. Please note that for duration values less than 10 ms, NOOP is used instead of IDLE. With IDLE, you generally want to stay in the IDLE stay for long intervals.